# Ubuntu boots in CLI after KDE uninstall

Tags: 12.04, command-line, kde

I installed KDE to see if it's better than Unity. I didn't like it, so I uninstalled it, but now, when I boot in Ubuntu, it just goes to command line, asking for a user and password. How can I get it to the "default" state that used the Unity GUI?

Comment: Kubuntu has its own display manager KDM. Ubuntu uses Lightdm as its sdisplay manager. It seems that your system doesn't know anymore that it has to use Lightdm as its display manager.

Comment: see the answers on : http://askubuntu.com/questions/278762/ubuntu-12-04-login-returns-to-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this at cli after login,

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

If it solves your issues. Open a terminal to edit the file `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` as

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

Add the following line there,

```
/usr/bin/lightdm
```

or

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

after this `lightdm` should start normally on reboot and bring you to the logon screen as usual.